# Object detection for uneven/Incomplete Objects

Tags: python, object-detection, object-tracking

Can anyone let me know how to detect uneven and incomplete objects so that the next step can be to track these particles/objects in a video?

Please specify wrt python.

Comment: A form of code would be beneficial.

Comment: You need to train your model with such examples. Objects that are occluded or partially visible make excellent samples to make a robust model

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example